# Run JetBrains Hub in a subdomain in a subfolder with Apache

Tags: apache, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-hub

I am using JetBrains tools to manage a team. Using Apache to manage my domains/subdomains. I have a sub domain named `dev.sepidarr.ir` which is responsible as the main entry point of my development environment.

**dev.sepidarr.ir.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /home/neacodin/domains/dev.sepidarr.ir/
  DirectoryIndex index.html

  <Directory "/home/neacodin/domains/dev.sepidarr.ir">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ServerName dev.sepidarr.ir
  ServerAlias www.dev.sepidarr.ir

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.dev.sepidarr.ir [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dev.sepidarr.ir
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

I want to have each JetBrains' tools running in a different url, for example I need `upsource` to run as `dev.sepidarr.ir/upsource` and `hub` in `dev.sepidarr.ir/hub`.

Based on the official [JetBrains tutorial about how to setup a reverse proxy server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/Proxy-Configuration.html), I have created a `.conf` file for `hub` as follow.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName dev.sepidarr.ir

  DefaultType none

  RewriteEngine on
  AllowEncodedSlashes on

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
  RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://localhost:8110/$1 [P]

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass /hub/ http://localhost:8110/hub
  ProxyPassReverse /hub/ http://localhost:8110/hub

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when I navigate to `dev.sepidarr.ir` it works fine. But when I try to open `dev.sepidarr.ir/hub` I get `404 Not Found`.

I have also configured hub to run with a custom base-url with the following command.

```
hub.sh configure--listen-port 8110 --base-url https://dev.sepidarr.ir/hub
```

But nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName dev.sepidarr.ir

... REST OF CONFIGS ...

<Location /hub>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8110/hub
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8110/hub
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now you can open `dev.sepidarr.ir/hub` and it shows `{your_server_id/localhost}:8110/hub` instead.

It's possible to add as much `Location` directive as you want.